# Unity 2D: I had an electricity blackout and now I can't load my scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, corruption, corrupt

I had an electric blackout tonight while working on a project, I saved like 10 minutes before said blackout so I wasn't too worried about loosing progress, when I opened up the project I was greeted by this error:

**"Unknown error occurred while loading 'Assets/Scenes/TestLevelTour.unity'."**

The scene is open but it's completely empty, even some prefabs I had been working on seem corrupted.

Is there a way to recover them?

I read about and tried clicking "Edit Unity scene file" in the .unity scene file, no luck, opens the empty scene again, displaying the same error message.

[image]

Comment: I assume you're not using git or other versioning control system, right?

Comment: Not at the moment, the last manual backup I did is 2 weeks old.